# error: After 5 attempts, peer0.org1 has failed to join channel 'mychannel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Trying to run through the ['Using the Test Network' example](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html#troubleshooting)  for Hyperledger Fabric - and getting a `After 5 attempts, peer0.org1 has failed to join channel 'mychannel'` error when attempting to run `./network.sh createChannel`.

I have verified that the network is up, and can see two orgs and an orderer when I run `docker ps -a`.

Additional errors:

```
2022-03-29 14:56:57.284 PDT 0001 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 962.331µs with error: EOF remoteaddress=[::1]:7051

Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

Comment: One of the common causes of this is the containers are re-using their volumes which contain old data and new certificates have been generated. Try doing a network.sh down then ensure you prune volumes using docker volume prune command and then bring up the network again

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall docker and install the recommended version.

The answer is found [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20try%20to%20create%20a%20channel%20with%20the%20command%20./network.sh%20createChannel%2C%20and%20it%20fails%20with%20the%20following%20error%3A)